# method in application_helper is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `twitter-bootstrap` for design. Here is my `layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
      <div class=" <%= flash_class type %> " >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <%= message %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

and `helpers/application_helper.rb` file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(type)
    case type
    when :alert
        "alert alert-error"
    when :notice
        "alert alert-success"
    else
        "alert"
    end
  end
end
```

my `flash_class` method is not working as I aspect . Everytime its call only `else` option. Don't know why ? If you need more information, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `type` given by the flash is a string. Did you try to compare using strings, rather than symbols?